# org.h2.message.DbException: IO Exception: "java.io.IOException: Error in parsing script, statement size exceeds 1G,

Tags: java, owasp-dependency-track

recently my H2 database of around 24 GB got corrupted. To recover the data i tried using command

```
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Recover
```

after that a txt file was generated of almost around 9GB.

Now again to convert the txt file to DB file i used the command

```
java -Xmx24G -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:~/Desktop/db -user sa -script db.txt
```

But I'm getting following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.message.DbException: IO Exception: "java.io.IOException: Error in parsing script, statement size exceeds 1G, first 80 characters of statement looks like: File E:/dbfile/db.mv.db, 25048920064 bytes, 23888 MB000000000 fileHeader H:2,bl" [90028-200]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.convertIOException(DbException.java:392)
        at org.h2.util.ScriptReader.readStatement(ScriptReader.java:101)
        at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:203)
        at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:192)
        at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:328)
        at org.h2.tools.RunScript.runTool(RunScript.java:143)
        at org.h2.tools.RunScript.main(RunScript.java:70)
```

How do i solve the issue